# major difference between url rewriting and hiding url

Tags: php, .htaccess

After much of researching i am confused with the difference between **url rewriting,pretty url and hiding url**...Though all the three almost performs the same functionality, but what is the difference between these three things?which is useful for SEO ? By seeing the URL can we identify whether is it just hiding url or url rewriting?

Comment: actually, `url rewriting` is the technique to get a `pretty url` or to `hide url`. For SEO `pretty url` is important.

Comment: To get better answers, you might want to add your definition of these three concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have been confused with the numerous terms that have been used in the articles and tutorials you have read.

Hopefully this will help out somewhat:

**Pretty URL**:
This is sometimes also called a search-engine friendly URL (because that's exactly what it is), and will generally look something like: `users/benmajor/profile/`
Google now places a lot of weighting on the URL a page is accessed with, so it's a good idea to follow this pattern.

**URL Rewriting**:
This is the actual technology used to convert a pretty URL into its system counterpart. For example, using Apache's `mod_rewrite` module, you can easily convert `users/benmajor/profile` into `profile.php?user=benmajor` using the following `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^users/[(.*)]/profile/?$ profile.php?user=$1
```

**URL Hiding**:
This one's a little more difficult to answer, since I don't know the context in which it was used, but I'm going to assume that this term simply means to hide the system URL (i.e. `profile.php?user=benmajor`) from the user.

Comment: THANKS THAT WAS GOOD ENOUGH FOR ME TO FURTHER UNDERSTAND